# Compile error: Using the generic type requires N type arguments

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I'm reading, "C# in a Nutshell" and i arrived to Advanced C# features first topic: delegates.

This simple code Works

```
using System;

namespace prueba
{
class Program
{
    public delegate int Transformer(int x);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Transformer t = Square;
        t += Cube;
        int result = t(3);
        Transform(5, Square);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static int Square(int x) => x * x;


    static int Cube(int x) => x * x * x;

    public static void Transform(int x, Transformer t){
        t(x);
    }
  }
} //prints => 27
```

When i try to use generics using this code

```
using System;

namespace prueba
{
class Program
{
    public delegate int Transformer<T>(T arg);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Transformer t = Square; // Compilation Error at this lane
        t += Cube;
        int result = t(3);
        Transform(5, Square);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static int Square(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        return 0;
    }

    static int Cube(int x) => x * x * x;

    public static void Transform<T>(T x, Transformer<T> t){
        t(x);
    }
  }
}
```

I Can't compile: [image: this]

I'm really new to this and i don't get what means that i require 1 type argument, when that the only thing i did is to change the int type delegate for a generic one (T). Could someone help me?

Comment: You're trying to use the generic type `Transformer<T>` without specifying `T`. This is not allowed when declaring a variable like this. You will have to be explicit and state `Transformer<int> = Square;`

Comment: oh, I see, thank you, i thought it works like dynamic var, but i was wrong, really thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, you're trying to use the generic type `Transformer<T>` without specifying any/all the generic arguments.

This is not allowed.

Your line of code will have to specify the `T` you want to use:

```
Transformer<int> t = Square;
```

Answer (score 2):

This means that your variable type requires a type argument when you define it:

```
Transformer<int> t = Square;
```

On the other hand, are you sure that you need to use a generic method here? Or will the delegate take other type of arguments besides `int`?

Comment: I was testing delegates feature, just in a test project, for check how it works :), btw thank you so much

Comment: @Ferus7 Yeah I actually figured that it probably was not a real-world case. You're welcome :)